# Error when installing devise- i am a novice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have installed rails and am running Git Bash and am on Windows 7 64 bit, i have installed gemfile and updated and this is my first use of ruby! I am following the instrustions from devise's github: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise . I am probably being very stupid but when i run gem 'devise' and this error occurs:

```
ERROR: while executing gem... <Gem::commandlinerror> unknown command /devise
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not installing gem properly.
gem install command is `gem install devise`

or perhaps you should add the gem to your Gemfile like this

```
 gem "devise"
```

and then run this command in your terminal

```
 bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `gem 'devise'` then it won't work because its not a valid command.

You should give

```
gem install devise
```

**or**

Include `gem 'devise'` in `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`